# Replacing Movie Clips with Sprites

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6, starling-framework

Hey everyone so I'm relatively new to AS3, I had a question. I'm developing a Mobile Application for Android devices and all my objects that are on the stage and that are added to the stage are Movie Clips. After awhile I begin to notice a drop in FPS. I know that this is due to me not using the devices GPU. Also I have read a lot about 3rd party programs that make use of the GPU and enhance the performance immensely such as the Starling framework. I've tried to implement that into my game and create the sprite sheets etc... But I just get error after error and i understand I'm not as advanced in AS3 to truly grasp how to use it.  So I was wondering if replacing the movie clips with sprites would enhance the performance? Or is that even possible. I know that Sprites are capable of working like move clips via able to add tweens etc... But will this enhance the performance of the game? Or am i pretty much screwed unless I learn how to use the starling framework?

Any help would be appreciated thanks everyone.

Comment: What do you mean under "drop of FPS after a while"? This might be because you are not freeing event listeners from all objects that you throw away by dereferencing. Make sure your app's memory usage does not climb at a steady pace prior to trying to optimize elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Just how many MovieClips do you think are bogging you down? What are those errors? I would not put your faith in a framework to save you from poor programming. Better to do good programming first. Sprites vs. MovieClips are probably not the answer. Post some code and specifics, please.